# Problems with developing incremental +1 function

Tags: vba, excel

i have a set of code which i am facing a problem with incremental numbers.
Please check this part on the "first bunch of code", I need help or guidance for my stuck part.

```
str = field1 & "|" & field2 & "|" & combine & "|"
```

I am trying to do some function which is similar to the "second bunch of codes" i've attached. The "second bunch of codes": if the date is equal to today's date, the number will increase incremental, let say if i save the excel sheet and i close it, when i reopen the sheets( second bunch of codes), the figures for [B2] will increase incrementally by +1.

I've been stuck for some times for the "first bunch of codes" as i need to make this part( on the first bunch of codes)

```
|" & combine & "|"
```

The output for my "first bunch of codes" ( just a sample )is

```
00|?????|AJ_20161216_001|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

The output is saved in File01.txt and the source is from "C:\File Header.xls"

For the "first bunch of codes", i need to make the 'combine' variable which is in the string incremental like the second bunch of codes without save and closing the excel and reopen it again to execute the incremental function by +1. Let say 
when i press the button, the first output will be

```
00|?????|AJ_20161216_001|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

When i press the button for second time the generated output must be( this part is also saved in file01.txt as the previous file01.txt that contained AJ_20161216_001 will be deleted )

```
00|?????|AJ_20161216_002|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

The codes below are the "first bunch of codes" i've been talking about

```
Sub CreatePFHeaderFooter()
Dim myfile As String
//file location
myfile = "C:\File Header.xls"
Application.Workbooks.Open FileName:=myfile
DatFile1Name = ThisWorkbook.path + "\File01.txt"
Open DatFile1Name For Output As #1 'create csv file

//declaration of all cell into variable
vRow = 2
While Cells(vRow, 1).Value <> ""
field1 = Cells(vRow, 1).Value
field2 = Cells(vRow, 2).Value
Field3 = Format(Now(), "AJ""_""YYYYMMDD""_")
'realfield3 = Cells(vRow, 3).Value

field4 = Cells(vRow, 4).Value
field5 = Cells(vRow, 5).Value
field6 = Cells(vRow, 6).Value
field7 = Cells(vRow, 7).Value
field8 = Cells(vRow, 8).Value
field9 = Cells(vRow, 9).Value
field10 = Cells(vRow, 10).Value
field11 = Cells(vRow, 11).Value
field12 = Cells(vRow, 12).Value
field13 = Cells(vRow, 13).Value
field14 = Cells(vRow, 14).Value
field15 = Cells(vRow, 15).Value
field16 = Cells(vRow, 16).Value
field17 = Cells(vRow, 17).Value
field18 = Cells(vRow, 18).Value
field19 = Cells(vRow, 19).Value
field20 = Cells(vRow, 20).Value
field21 = Cells(vRow, 21).Value
field22 = Cells(vRow, 22).Value
field23 = Cells(vRow, 23).Value
field24 = Cells(vRow, 24).Value
field25 = Cells(vRow, 25).Value
field26 = Cells(vRow, 26).Value
field27 = Cells(vRow, 27).Value
field28 = Cells(vRow, 28).Value
field29 = Cells(vRow, 29).Value

//Incomplete parts
Dim str As String
Dim calc As Long
calc = 1 + 1
formcalc = Format(calc, "000")
combine = 0
combine1 = ""

//This is the part where i got stuck
If [C2] = "" Then
  combine = Field3 + formcalc
Else

str = ""
str = field1 & "|" & field2 & "|" & combine & "|" & field4 & "|" & field5 & "|" & field6 & "|" & field7 & "|" & field8 & "|" & field9 & "|" & field10 & "|"
str = str & field11 & "|" & field12 & "|" & field13 & "|" & field14 & "|" & field15 & "|" & field16 & "|" & field17 & "|" & field18 & "|" & field19 & "|" & field20 & "|"
str = str & field21 & "|" & field22 & "|" & field23 & "|" & field24 & "|" & field25 & "|" & field26 & "|" & field27 & "|" & field28 & "|" & field29 & "|"


Print #1, str
vRow = vRow + 1

Wend
Close #1

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Here are the "second bunch of code" which is similar function i need to do for the first bunch of codes

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If [B1] = "" Then
    [B1] = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    [B2] = 1
Else
    If Trim([B1]) <> Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") Then
        [B1] = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        [B2] = 1
Else
    [B1] = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    [B2] = [B2] + 1
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Sorry, i apologise for the unorganised formats.

Comment: `calc` has to be declared outside of the Sub for it's value to be preserved.

Comment: okay, noted, i will make the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated tasks should be extracted from the main subroutine into their own subroutine.

Here I created `getNewID` to increment the ID.

You should not have a delimiter after the last cell.  This will create an empty column that will cause issues reading the file.

> str = field1 & "|" & ... & field29 & "|"

```
Sub CreatePFHeaderFooter()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim data(1 To 29) As String
    Dim myfile As String
    'file location
    myfile = "C:\File Header.xls"
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile
    DatFile1Name = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\File01.txt"
    Open DatFile1Name For Output As #1    'create csv file

    x = 2
    While Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(x, 3) = "" Then Cells(x, 3) = getNewID(Cells(x - 1, 3))

        For y = 1 To 28
            data(y) = Cells(x, y)
        Next

        Print #1, Join(data, "|")
        x = x + 1
    Wend

    Close #1

    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub

Function getNewID(OldID As String) As String
    Dim arr() As String, strDate As String
    Dim d As Date

    arr = Split(OldID, "_")
    strDate = arr(1)
    d = DateSerial(Left(strDate, 4), Mid(strDate, 5, 2), Right(strDate, 2))

    If d = Date Then
        arr(2) = Format(CInt(arr(3)) + 1, "000")
    Else
        arr(1) = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
        arr(2) = "001"
    End If

    getNewID = Join(arr, "_")
End Function
```

Comment: @lyeyannian is `getNewID` in a standard module?

Comment: hi, ignore this problem, i've solved it, now i've met the last problem, if i add messagebox after the end of function getnewID , i will get compile error: only comments may appear after end sub, end function, or end property.

Comment: @lyeyannian You should watch this series: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).   This is pretty relavent:  [Excel VBA Introduction Part 3 - What to do When Things Go Wrong (Errors and Debugging)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlqKfYTgc9Q&index=3&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&t=40s)

Comment: @lyeyannian you need to have the `MsgBox` enclosed inside a `Sub` or `Function`.  Alternately, you could call the `MsgBox` from the Immediate Window.  Watch the first 3 videos in the series that I linked you and you'll have a much better understanding of the VBA.

Comment: Thank you for the videos link, i will go through these video, i've been through first two episode, it's really nice and easy to understand.